# Power of Bernoulli likelihood in Jags (R2jags)

Tags: r, bayesian, prior, jags, stan

In a fixed power prior model, the model is set up as:

$$ \pi(p_i \mid \alpha,\mathcal{D}_0) \propto L(p_i\mid \mathcal{D}_0)^{w} \pi(p_i) $$

Suppose that the event follows a Bernoulli distribution with probability $p_i$, what I want is to raise the Bernoulli likelihood to the power of $w$ in jags:

```
mod1<-function(){
  for(i in 1 : N) {
    y[i] ~ dbern(p[i])^w #<-------- 
    logit(p[i]) <- a[group[i]] + t[group[i]]*d[i]
  }
  for (j in 1:3) {
    a[j] ~ dnorm(mu.a, pow(sd.a,-2))
    t[j] ~ dnorm(mu.t, pow(sd.t,-2))
  }
  mu.a~dnorm(0,0.01)
  mu.t~dnorm(0,0.01)
  sd.a ~ dunif(0,10)
  sd.t ~ dunif(0,10)
}
```

However, JAGS does not recognize such code.

As an alternative, I wrote the following STAN code:

```
mod1 <- '
data {
  int<lower = 1> N;
  real w;
  int y[N];
  vector[N] d;
  int group[N];
  }

parameters {
  vector[3] a;
  vector<lower=0>[3] t;
  real mua;
  real mut;
  real sigmaa;
  real sigmat;
}

model {
  real p[N];
  //prior
  mua~normal(0,10);
  mut~normal(0,10);
  sigmaa ~ uniform(0,10);
  sigmat ~ uniform(0,10);
  for (j in 1:3) {
  a[j] ~ normal(mua, sigmaa); 
  t[j] ~ normal(mut, sigmat);
  }
  
  //likelihood

  for (i in 1:N) {
    p[i]=inv_logit(a[group[i]] + t[group[i]]*d[i]);
    target += bernoulli_lpmf(y[i]|(p[i]))*w;
  }
}
'
```

which works, but I'd like to use JAGS (R2jags) for this project and was wondering if there is a JAGS equivalent for the above STAN code. Thanks!